# Webpage table updated by uploading file

Tags: java, php, html, xml

I am looking to create a web page displaying football league table which can be updated by uploading a file, such as XML (preferred).

If I was to create this in java, what data store should I use for the league?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just make a MySQL database, write your web-page using JSP/JSTL and write something to update the database by reading the XML sheet.

Some Alternatives:
You could always just use a hierarchical file scheme with each folder representing a table in the database, each file in that folder representing a column in the table.

You could store it directly in XML:

```
<xml>
  <tableName>
    <columnName>
      <data1/>
      <data2/>
    </columnName>
    <columnName2>
    </columnName2>
  </tableName>
</xml>
```

Comment: I'm trying to do it without MySQL, which I could do pretty easily. I'm thinking maybe using another XML file to store the league table?

Comment: You could always just use a hierarchical file scheme with each folder representing a table in the database, each file in that folder representing a column in the table. 
Alternatively, you could store it directly in XML: 

`<xml>
  <tableName>
    <columnName>
      <data1/>
      <data2/>
    </columnName>
    <columnName2>
    </columnName2>
  </tableName>
</xml>`

Comment: Yeah, I have decided to use XML files, and use a php web page as the parsing involves a lot less coding than java. Cheers dude.